# More than one value in a same field

Tags: filter

I want to make a view in which I see only the minor versions (X.1, X.2, X.3, etc.)

There is no way I can do that. Filtering the versions by « contains = .1 » doesn't work. And I only have 10 possible filters so I cannot filter by « different from = 1.0 » and list all the versions ending in .0.

May I put more than one value in the same field since it calls to the same column, « Version »?

I also tried to filter by « different from = #.0 » or « different from = *.0 » which would be perfect but it did not work. :(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:
Create a new `calculated` column called `VersionMinor` with this formula: `=IF(ROUND(Version,0)=VALUE(Version),0,1)`

Set the data type to `Number` and `Number of decimal places` to 0

It will contain 1 for all items where the Version contains a minor version, and 0 for major versions.

Then, in your view you can use the following filter: `VersionMinor is equal to 1`